# How to create a terraform map of list

Tags: terraform

I have a variable which is as below, and I am trying to make a map as below

```
   "network1" = {
      name                = "network1"
      private_dns_zone_names = ["privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net", "privatelink.azuredatabricks.net", "privatelink.database.windows.net", "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net", "privatelink.dfs.core.windows.net"]


    } },


    "network2" = {
      name                = "network2"
      private_dns_zone_names = ["privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net", "privatelink.azuredatabricks.net", "privatelink.database.windows.net", "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net", "privatelink.dfs.core.windows.net"]
```

I want to create a map like below

```
{
   
    "vnetname" = "network1"
   "private_dns_zone_names" = "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"
    "private_dns_zone_names" = "privatelink.azuredatabricks.net"
    "private_dns_zone_names" = "privatelink.database.windows.net"
  },
```

Comment: You cannot do that, the keys in the map have to be unique.